# How to have multiple data types for form body with swagger in aspnet core mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

Currently my swagger output as a body parameter that looks like this

```
      {
        "name": "body",
        "in": "body",
        "description": "",
        "required": true,
        "type": "file"
      }
```

and i read the documentation that the type property can be a array of types

```
      {
        "name": "body",
        "in": "body",
        "description": "",
        "required": true,
        "type": [null,"file"]
      }
```

but I have found no way to tell aspnet core mvc or swaggerGen to output two types? Is this possible.

I would like the swaggerUI to include the option to either select a file or post some json data. Can this be done?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and i read the documentation that the type property can be a array of types
>
> ```
> "type": [null,"file"]
> ```

This is not valid in OpenAPI/Swagger. `type` must be a single type, and there's no `null` type.

> I would like the swaggerUI to include the option to either select a file or post some json data.

In OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0 this is not possible –  an operation can post either a file or JSON but not both. You'll need two operations - one that accepts JSON, and another one that accepts a file.

What you want will be possible using OpenAPI 3.0. However, I don't know if ASP.NET Core MVC supports OpenAPI 3.0; it may take some time before tools adopt the new version of OpenAPI.

Your API spec (in YAML) would look like this:

```
paths:
  /something:
    post:
      requestBody:
        description: Either a file or JSON object
        required: true
        content:

          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object:
              properties:
                ...

          # Post a file via a multipart request
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                file:    # <-- here "file" is a form field name
                  type: string
                  format: binary
              required:
                - file

          # or maybe...
          # Post a file directly
          application/octet-stream:
            schema:
              type: string
              format: binary

      responses:
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am forking and manipulating the swagger tools myself so no problem making it generate the v3 stuff.

Comment: that said, have you seen any UI generators for v3 ?

Comment: If you mean UI renderers - Swagger UI 3.1.0 added OAS 3 rendering, but no "try it out" yet (you can track [#3338](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3338) for updates).